# Magento2 configurable product slow

Tags: performance, magento2, configurable-product

I'm creating some configurable products on Magento 2.3, I set color and size as configurable attributes. I need to set for each color a specific product images. When I save the product with the configurable option it takes long time (about 2-3 minutes), after that I get a 503 error, the product is saved but the procedure takes alot of time.
When I create the configurable product with same attributes options but without images the saving time is normal.

I try to edit php limit memory, switch to production mode, switch from built in to varnish cache, no result, it's faster but when I upload some images it's very slow.

Comment: Have you check magento log file? may be some error when you save configurable product

Comment: @Jinesh Yes no error in logs. the 503 page seems like a request timeout page. But I don't understand why the saving takes so long time

Comment: have you install any extension? Can you tell me at what time this error comes?

Comment: @Jinesh , yes I have some extensions installed. Should I disable all extensions and give a try? This error come when I'm saving the product, I set the colors and sizes attributes, upload two images for each color , then when I press save after 2-3 minutes the product is still saving and I get the 503 error. If I save the product with colors and sizes but without images it works without errors.

Comment: Yes You can disable those extension then check it

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. no extensions in the loop. any resolution?

Comment: I have same issue , can anybody have solution?